# Notion API - filter database by created_time?

Tags: notion-api

I'm trying to filter database entries based on the creation time, but tried many different combinations of filter and I always get an error. Sorting works fine.

I've also tried `property: 'created_time'` and `date: {after:since}` but it always complains that there's a property missing from the filter.

```
const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: DATABASE_ID,
    filter: {
      timestamp: 'created_time',
      created_time: {after: since},
    },
    sorts: [
      {
        timestamp: 'created_time',
        direction: 'ascending',
      },
    ],
  });
```

error:

```
@notionhq/client warn: request fail {
  code: 'validation_error',
  message: 'body failed validation. Fix one: body.filter.or should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.and should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.title should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.text should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.rich_text should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.select should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.multi_select should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.people should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.files should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.url should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.email should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.phone should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.created_by should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.property should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.last_edited_by should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.last_edited_time should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.formula should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.filter.rollup should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

filter should be:

```json
{
  "filter": {
    "timestamp": "created_time",
    "created_time": {
      "after": "2022-04-11T07:04:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Looks close, other issue could be using an outdated api version that doesn't support the date filter object, make sure to add most recent `Notion-Version` header: https://developers.notion.com/reference/versioning